# Converting a 12V pulse to a shorter 24V pulse?

Tags: voltage, solenoid

I have a bunch of Point-of-Sale printers which can emit a ca. 1 second long 12V pulse in order to open the attached cash-drawer.

Because of a procurement SNAFU, I now also have a bunch of cash drawers which would like a 24V pulse to activate the solenoid and open the drawer.

In spite of this, the 12V pulse USUALLY works. But not always.

So, my question is: is there a way to convert the 12V, 1 second pulse to e.g. a 24V, 0.5 second pulse, using only basic electronics which would NOT require an additional power source?

Comment: Seems probable. Any idea on the amperage requirement for these drawers?

Comment: How easy it is depends on the current consumption of the drawers, the supply capability of the printers, the pulse duration the drawers really need, and whether tricks like a very short 24v pulse followed by a longer 12v duration would work well. I can think of several methods worth trying, depending on answers to those.

Comment: as a sketch, my first thought is for a single pulse boost converter. A series inductor is switched to ground initially, the 12v pulse builds current through the inductor. After a while, the switch goes off, tripped on current or time, and the inductor drives current into the load, raising its voltage. After a while, the inductor energy runs out, and the load voltage drops back to 12v, caught by a diode across the inductor. Problem - it would need a fairly hefty iron-cored inductor for any significant pulse duration, not a component most people like to play with these days.

Comment: in my experience these drawers only need a brief pulse on the solenoid to open the not even a quarter of a second. but longer pulses do not do any harm.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers!

I will give an adjustable 5$ DC-DC converter from Amazon a try, and if that doesn't work, I'll try the circuits you guys provided.

Answer (score 2):

buy a bunch of $1 boost converters from your favourite online marketplace.
the drawer will not be adversely effected by the longer pulse.

buy some heatshrink too to house it in.

Comment: this is easiest and cheapest way to solve the problem. it's don't vote it down just because it's not doing circuit design.

Comment: If the drawers are built like for like, then I would expect the 24v drawer to draw half the current of the 12v drawer. With luck then,  a 12v to 24v converter powering a 24v drawer should take much the same current as the 12v drawer, so be OK from the 12v printer pulse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following idea (charge-pump-like):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLlcsJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this configuration the two capacitors are charged in parallel to 12V each.
Switching to this configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4RG0e.png)</sup>

makes the caps to be connected in series, thus producing 24V on the designated point.

Of course this circuit should be augmented with some automatic switching logic (transistors/comparators), and the pulse might be not very "square" one, but it is a general idea.

**Update:** Actually there is no need in the `C1` capacitor, if the input is remaining 12V there..

Answer (score 1):

another way to double voltage, but this is fairly hard on the relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSI1Qk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

rly2 represents the cash drawer solenoid 1M resistor is jut to help the simulation resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the situation of charging a capacitor up to 12V via an inductor. Due to losses, eventually the capacitor attains a steady state voltage of 12V but, between 12V first being applied and the steady state situation is a whole different story.

So the capacitor starts charging up and the current through the inductor attains a peak value as the capacitor capacitor voltage reaches 12V. At this point the energy stored in the inductor continues to raise the capacitor voltage higher and eventually there is no current left in the inductor i.e. all the energy has gone.

The voltage on the capacitor is 24 volts and this voltage is about to fall and repeat like this: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [swarthmore.edu](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Transient/TransInputs/TransStep/imgBC1.gif))</sub>

For a very low damping ratio i.e. very low dc resistance in the coil, the first peak will hit 24V then subside down to 0V then rise up to 24V continuing basically forever if the damping ratio is zero. Of course it won't be zero but you might hit a 1st peak of 22V for instance.

Now here's the trick the inductor is placed in series with a diode so that the capacitor charges up to about 21 volts and (wait for it...) stops there. There's no more energy left in the inductor and a stable situation has arisen. The capacitor remains charged at over 20 volts.

You could then use that capacitor to discharge energy into the solenoid that opens the cash draw on your POS system. Here is a simulation: -

[image]

The blue trace rises to about 22+ volts in about 3 milli seconds. The red trace is the current through the inductor. About 24 mJ are stored in the capacitor. If this isn't enough to activate the solenoid then a bigger cap and inductor are required and a longer time delay to charge can be expected.

Comment: you'd need some way to detect the voltage peak and then connect the drawer.

Comment: @Jasen the point is that the capacitor is likely to stay charged up for hours and hours if not days so, when the 12v pulse occurs, it can activate a mosfet to do the business end of driving the solenoid.

Comment: so, charge the capacitor on the rising edge and then activate the mosfet on the falling edge?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a 1:1 transformer -- just connect the primary to the 12 V source, and connect the secondary between the 12 V pin and the drawer solenoid. Connect the other end of the solenoid to the ground of the 12 V source.

In this case, the polarity of the transformer windings matters -- and they are unlikely to be labelled. If it doesn't work, then exchange the terminals of either the primary or secondary.

However, I don't know where to get a suitable transformer :-(

Comment: such a transformer would be immense, 0.5Hz is a low frequency..

Comment: Yes it would be large (his pulse is 0.5 s ==> 1 Hz). However if (say) the pulse could be shortened to 0.1 s, then he applies 12 V* 0.1s, or 1.2 Vs on the transformer. A 110 V rated 60 Hz transformer takes about 110 * (1/60/2) = 0.9 Vs which is close and would likely work.
Basically, you need the inductance of the transformer high enough that it doesn't saturate within the duration of the applied pulse